# Why does the thread loop infinitely?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using VS2010 .Net 4.0, so I cannot use the `await` calls. I have one thread downloading something, and I shouldn't continue before the status becomes "Done". So I am using a while loop blocking the thread. But somehow it becomes an infinite loop. Am I creating the thread properly?

```
string status = string.Empty;
Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    status = Download(downloadKit, patchTitle);
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();

// Loops here forever
while (status != "Done")
{
    //Thread.Sleep(25); // Tried this as well, same result
    Thread.SpinWait(1);
}
```

Comment: Probably because `status` never gets the chance to change.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) on the Status=download statement and rerun your program.  When you hit that statement press F11 to single step into Download method.

Comment: we have to beleive that the Download code returns Done at some point. I assume it does not.

Comment: Also this code doesn't reach the while operator, because it wait on thread.Join();

Comment: What's the point of waiting for the download to complete after you've already waited for it to complete by joining the thread that does the download?!

Comment: Use "volatile" to indicate that one thread updates a variable used by others.  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Comment: I would recommend looking into async/await. It provides a simpler way to do this without directly messing with threads. :)

Comment: have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @David Schwartz you should post that as an answer. Other comments / answers so far are completely missing that problem and suggesting unnecessary changes to the OP's code that are going to lead him wayyy off course.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows Ya, only you get what I was trying to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that `thread.Join();` blocks in the calling thread until the thread being joined terminates. Once you understand that, you'll see that it is silly to do a while loop in the calling thread on the value of status, as if you've passed the join then the value of status will never change again unless you add code that does so.

```
string status = string.Empty;
Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    status = Download(downloadKit, patchTitle);
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();

//no point in looping here, if the thread finished, it has already assigned the
//value it is going to assign to the status variable
if (status == "Done")
{
    //do what needs to be done
}
else
{
   //uh oh, handle the failure here
}
```

To address the requirement that you cannot continue until `status=="Done"`, you could instead place your while loop inside the child thread so that it keeps attempting the Download function until it returns "Done":

```
string status = string.Empty;
Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    while(status != "Done")
        status = Download(downloadKit, patchTitle);
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();

//do what needs to be done
```

Answer (score 0):

Threading can result in some weird stuff sometimes, you need to sometimes tell the compiler that you are preforming something unsafe, you can do that by doing a `var nstatus = Volatile.Read( ref status )` and then compare against that.

```
string nstatus = status;
// Loops here forever
while (nstatus != "Done")
{
    //Thread.Sleep(25); // Tried this as well, same result
    Thread.SpinWait(1);
    nstatus = Volatile.Read(ref status);
}
```

Other alternative is to use a `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` call, (which what I believe is being done in the Volatile call ), which prevents reordering of statements by compiler:

```
// Loops here forever
while (status != "Done")
{
    //Thread.Sleep(25); // Tried this as well, same result
    Thread.SpinWait(1);
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
}
```

A good resource to look at would be http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx , very in depth look at threading in .NET 4.0